What number fits in the ? spot?
Your solution needs to hold for all steps of the puzzle and the rule you use must be simple to understand (no high-order polynomials or other complex rule needed).
Note: The 9 at the bottom is not a typo
Puzzle inspired by Nob Yoshigahara's famous number puzzle


This is similar to Nob Ishighiara's classic puzzle https://braineaser.com/brainteasers/nobs-number-tree/

Yes, it was inspired by that puzzle (as I mention in the description). I applied a similar concept to a different pair of potential rules.

The ? may be

 18

Following the pattern of

 summing all the digits in the row above like
 (9 + 9) + (3 + 5 + 6 + 4) --> 36
 (3 + 6) + (9 + 7 + 2) --> 27
 (2 + 7) + ( 1 + 0 + 8) --> 18
 (1 + 8) + ( 6 + 0) --> 15
 (1 + 5) + (1 + 2 + 0) --> 9


Great! Do you like this puzzle?

@Rob - yes, though you could make it tougher.

There are actually only a relatively small number of ways for this trick to work. I did develop a couple other ones but this one seemed the most beautiful. Did you find the "trick" solution first?

I see @Rob, you noted 'the 9 at the bottom is not a typo', so there's some method pointing to a different solution until the final 9. Oh no, I haven't found that one, so perhaps I was lucky .

Yes, that's right. Funny that you found the real solution first!

The 9 might look like a type if you assume that in each step the product of the two numbers on the left gives the number on the right. That works for every step with a 4 at the ? but would require an 8 at the bottom instead of a 9.

That's right! It's amazing that these numbers work for both rules all the way until the end.
